# Ros Melodic on 20.04

Tags: 20.04

04 that is just installed. I install it to use Ros but now I learn that on 20.04 Ros Melodic is not able to be used so how can I turn it into 18.04 or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 supports only ROS Noetic. If you are not particular about using Melodic, you can install Noetic. But if you want Melodic, and don't want to take the burden of building from source and solving the issues, it is better that you do a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 and install ROS melodic in that.

Answer (score 0):

Further to S.Baktha Kohahalan answer, you can check the versions on https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

ROS Melodic is made for

- Ubuntu Artful (17.10)
- Ubuntu Bionic (18.04)

ROS Neotic is made for

- Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04)

I had the same issue, using Ubuntu 20.04 I was not able to install Melodic, but Noetic installation worked smooth with the step-by-step instructions on http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu